# How to clear the clipboard contents using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, clipboard

I have an application where I am using the clipboard for copy and paste operations. For copying I have used this code:

```
Clipboard.Clear();
const byte VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x43, 0, 0, 0); // Send the C key (43 is "C")
keybd_event(0x43, 0, CONST_KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, CONST_KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

But it's giving an error saying **Unable to perform the clipboard action**, and I am unable to paste it. It's throwing an exception.

How do I fix this issue or are there some other ways to clear the clipboard content before we copy?

Comment: Unable to Perform the Clipboard Action

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Copy empty string using Clipboard.SetText(string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952960/copy-empty-string-using-clipboard-settextstring)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it using Win32 API calls ([EmptyClipboard function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649037(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Clipboard.SetText("some string");
Clipboard.GetText();
```

See the MSDN article *[Clipboard Class (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx)*.

Comment: Basically i am trying to overwrite the CTRL+C functionality in my application.  i.e., whenever us er presses hot key, then the selected text should be copied into clipboard. I don't know, what the user going to select, so i can't use setText.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clipboard.Clear()
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx)