# Copy empty string using Clipboard.SetText(string)

Tags: c#, clipboard

`Clipboard.SetText("")` throws me an error - "Value cannot be null". So how do I copy an empty string using `Clipboard.SetText`?

I have already done `Clipboard.Clear()`. It does clear the clipboard, but it doesn't help me to **paste an empty string**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to paste empty string? Do you need paste new line?

Comment: Probably the same issue as me : he wanted to keep it nice and simple without a special case when the selection is an empty string. I'm curious to know if there's a technical reason for preventing an empty string when a "normal" string is allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you try to save null or an empty string using `Clipboard.SetText` it will never work.

See *[Clipboard.SetText Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k.aspx)* (MSDN). It mentions ArgumentNullException is thrown if the text is null or `Empty` for `Clipboard.SetText`.

Hence you cannot achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: POLA violation if I've ever seen one ;) "We throw an Argument*Null*Exception for non-null values" ... whut?!

Answer (score 10):

I think you need to do

```
Clipboard.Clear()
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CLIPBOARD.CLEAR%29;k%28CLEAR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

> Clears any data from the system Clipboard.

Comment: That is a more useful answer.

Comment: That doesn't work in multi-threaded applications. `The current thread is not in single-threaded apartment (STA) mode. Add the STAThreadAttribute to your application's Main method.`

Answer (score 4):

See *[Clipboard.Clear Method (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.clear.aspx)* (MSDN).

```
Clipboard.Clear();
```

will clear the clipboard, so you will "paste" an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Reference `PresentationCore` and call [`System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k.aspx). I used [clipview](http://www.peterbuettner.de/develop/tools/clipview/) to verify that `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText("");` (which throws no exception) stores the empty string into the clipboard.

This method it saves you from having to conditionally call `Clear()` or `SetText()` depending on what string you are trying to effectively set into clipboard. This is especially useful if you’re trying to write code to set the clipboard to **any string value** without knowing ahead of time whether or not the empty string needs to be supported. I.e., this method enables you to avoid treating the empty string like a special case (IMO, it shouldn’t be a special case because that’s just confusing).

Additionally, as can be seen with clipview, `Clear()` actually empties out the clipboard instead of placing an empty string in it. Calling `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText("")` actually puts an empty string value into clipboard. When you paste, the target application can tell the difference and actually behave differently if it wants to.

Comment: Re: *"Reference `PresentationCore.dll`"*: Or perhaps just use `PresentationCore` in the ".NET" tab (the first tab)?

Comment: When I tried this, with `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText()`,I got an **exception for an empty string** (as for the `Forms` one), but no exception for a non-empty string. Is it dependent on the .NET version? C# versions? "Path" in the reference "PresentationCore" (under ***References*** in the C# project) was: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationCore.dll`

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have the same path in References. I’m running Windows 10 build 15007 which claims to have .net-4.7 but also under “Turn Windows features on or off” it says I have .net-3.5, so I think when I target .net-3.5 it is actually running on .net-3.5 but it’s probably the latest patched version. I can’t figure out how to get `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText()` to throw on empty string. Are you sure you’re not actually passing it `null` instead of an empty string?